# Is it possible to parallel retrieve values from an Excel file using OpenXML?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, openxml, parallel.foreach

I have implemented a variant of the following get cell value (see [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-retrieve-the-values-of-cells-in-a-spreadsheet?redirectedfrom=MSDN)) and I use this to read an Excel tabel. However, due to the slow pace of reading every cell, I have implemented a parallel foreach:

```
                DataTable resultTable = DataManager.GetEmptyCredentialsTable();
                ParallelOptions options = new ParallelOptions();
                options.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1;

                // Parallel loading Excel row data.
                Parallel.ForEach<int, DataTable>(
                    rowNumberArray,
                    options,
                    // Creating subsets of the credentials table to be loaded in.
                    () => DataManager.GetEmptyCredentialsTable(),
                    (int r, ParallelLoopState loop, DataTable dt) =>
                    {
                        string clientName = GetCellData(wbPart, wspCredentials, "B" + r.ToString());

                    // There has to be a client name in order to parse the data row.
                    if (clientName != null && clientName != "")
                        {
                            dt.Rows.Add(GetRow(wbPart, wspCredentials, dt, r));
                        }
                        return dt;
                    },
                    final_dt =>
                    {
                        lock (resultTable)
                        {
                            resultTable.Merge(final_dt);
                        }
                    });
```

But this does not work properly if we set the `options.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2` , because OpenXML does not seem to support this. Does someone have a solution to retrieve the cell values from an Excel document in a bit more speedy manner? Or perhaps can we circumvent the parallel access limitations?